# How to find number of all occurrences of the last written Word/String in rich text box?

Tags: c#, .net, string, split, richtextbox

I have a rich text box in which i am triggering the keypress event with spacebar. The logic to find number of all occurrences of the last written word which i have implemented is:

```
private void textContainer_rtb_KeyPress_1(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //String lastWordToFind;
        if (e.KeyChar == ' ')
        {
            int i = textContainer_rtb.Text.TrimEnd().LastIndexOf(' ');
            if (i != -1)
            {
                String lastWordToFind = textContainer_rtb.Text.Substring(i + 1).TrimEnd();

                int count = new Regex(lastWordToFind).Matches(this.textContainer_rtb.Text.Split(' ').ToString()).Count;
                MessageBox.Show("Word: " + lastWordToFind + "has come: " + count + "times");
            }

        }
    }
```

But its not working. Can somebody please point out the error or rectify it?

Comment: After trimming, space goes off.so i always be -1

Comment: @usercr It wouldn't remove internal spaces, just trailing (for `TrimEnd`) spaces.

Comment: your last char is space, so it goes off after TrimEnd()

Comment: Yes, but if the text is `"some text with spaces "`, then the trim will return `"some text with spaces"` and the index should be 14.

Comment: @Cemafor I agree man! It only removes the white spaces from ending not internal spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex doesn't work lilke this:

```
int count = new Regex(lastWordToFind).Matches(this.textContainer_rtb.Text.Split(' ').ToString()).Count;
```

this part:

```
this.textContainer_rtb.Text.Split(' ').ToString()
```

will split your text into array of strings:

```
string s = "sss sss sss aaa sss";
string [] arr = s.Split(' ');
```

**arr** is like this after split:

> ```
> arr[0]=="sss"
> arr[1]=="sss"
> arr[2]=="sss"
> arr[3]=="aaa"
> arr[4]=="sss"
> ```

then **ToString()** returns type name:

```
System.String[]
```

So what you're really doing is:

```
int count = new Regex("ccc").Matches("System.String[]").Count;
```

That's why it doesn't work. You should simply do:

```
 int count = new Regex(lastWordToFind).Matches(this.textContainer_rtb.Text).Count;
```

Comment: `lastWordToFind` is used as a Regex pattern here (and in original code). So if the last "word" the user typed was something like `.*`, it would match more than just every `.*`.  Also substrings would be counted as matchs. If the last word was "a", then the "a" in "cat" would be a match. It may be best to just split the text and look for exact matches in the array.

Comment: +1 for Arie! thanks a loads for correcting me! God bless you! It worked.

Comment: @Cemafor I agree but then it should be done with for example Linq not regex

Comment: Yeah i was geting the typename instead of the string value which i was ignoring! Thanks Arie and Cemafor!

Answer (score 0):

You Regex appears to be incorrect.  Try the following.

```
String lastWordToFind = textContainer_rtb.Text.Substring(i + 1).TrimEnd();
// Match only whole words not partial matches
// Remove if partial matches are okay
lastWordToFind = @"\b" + word + @"\b";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, word).Count);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there is nothing wrong with the Regex as what i have done is to call the regex constructor with a parameter as a pattern to find the match in rich text box tracing each and every occurrence of the pattern. To be more succinct, its the alternative way you have provided. Thanks!